# Best way to handle 8 frames(images) of animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation

I have 8 .pngs that when i use them fast in sequence its looks like a nice animation of a hand opening and closing.

The way I could do this is to create a UIImageView and then use an NSTimer to call a function every 200 milliseconds to change the image shown by the UIImageView to the next image in the sequence.

Is there a better way of doing this that I don't know of on the iphone?

Many Thanks
-Code

Comment: Have you tried [Cocos2d?](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/)

Comment: Which part of Cocoa2sd? I've used it before to rotate an image.

Comment: `CCAnimation` is like a framebuffer of sprites.  You can even pre-load it into a `CCAnimationCache` so you just call the action on the sprite whenever you need it.  Quite useful.  I use it [here.](http://strongfortress.com/blog/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your images are not too big:

```
imgView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"],
                           ...
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"img7.png"],
                           [UIImage imageNamed:@"img8.png"],
                           nil];
imgView.animationDuration = /* anim duration in seconds */;
```

Answer (score 0):

UIImageView has everything you need built in. Check out the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) heading "Animating Images"